# Standing desk while working

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, calories

Because I'm a [web developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Qun.jpg) I usually work about 9-12 hours per day. 2 months ago I was 108kg(238 pounds) and after a hard eating plan and some exercise now I'm 97kg(213 pounds). My height is 1.83m (72.05 in). I'm usually eating about 1500-1800 calories per day and I'm working out about 30-40 minutes with some fitness blender workout kickboxing videos. I'm trying to drop some more kilos but I stucked at 97kg. I've read somewhere that if I'm working on a standing desk I'll lose more calories. Is it true? I can't workout for longer time because of my schedule. I've seen some calculators which showed me that if I'm standing lets say for one hour I'll lose about 250 calories.

And my main question is: Should I invest in a standing desk? Or this is an another marketing viral scam? What else can I do if this isn't true?

Comment: 1500-1800 calories/day seems quite low for someone of your size and activity level, even for losing weight. As for the standing desk, as far as I know the main benefit is to promote good posture rather than burn calories.

Comment: Yeah quite low but I stucked at 97 kg. for about 2 and a half weeks and also I can't rid much of the body fat anymore. I don't want "beach body" or something like this.

Comment: The answer is to 1) make sure you are getting proper nutrition, water, and sleep, 2) do some resistance training 2-3 times per week (eg, lifting weights) to complement the cardio you already do, and 3) be patient. Gimmicks like standing desks or extreme calorie cutting are not the way to go.

Comment: Here are some other q/a about [standing desks](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/should-i-get-rid-of-my-office-chair/7918#7918) and some people like [treadmill desks](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4328/treadmill-desks-do-they-work-when-trying-to-lose-weight-and-what-are-potentia).

Answer (score 2):

First let me say I haven't used a standing desk, however I'm in the software development field and know where you're coming from with sitting long hours. I'm also a personal trainer and see a lot of clients with bad backs due to poor posture from sitting long hours.

A standing desk will help you lose a few calories, however I cant vouch for how many and if its really worth the cost. The desk will also make sure you keep a good posture when working so that's another positive.

I would look into desk that mounts to a wall and slides up or down, allowing you to stand or sit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think is good idea as I standing to make "steps", to push a little more the calories? (and simultaneously coding :P )